# Views won't flip if forcefully changing App language

Tags: ios, cocoa, autolayout

I am developing app that will change language within app regardless the system languages. Working great with `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@[@"fr"] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];`. Now i am integrating RTL, all strings are replacing perfectly but view are not flipping. What could be the problem?

Comment: You can't set `NSView`'s property `flipped`. It is readonly.

Comment: @Willeke Can you please guide what to use instead